# How can I set environment variables in my Linux service for Asterisk even though it doesn't have a real user?

Tags: linux, perl, bash, asterisk, init.d

I have created a linux service that runs as a deamon (and gets started from /etc/init.d/X). I need to set some environment variables that can be accessed by the application.

Here's the scenario. The application is a bunch of Perl AGI scripts that depend on (and therefore need to run as) asterisk user but asterisk doesn't have a shell. Ideally I'd just set this in */home/asterisk/.bashrc* but that doesn't exist for asterisk.

How can I set environment variables for my app in the asterisk user's running environment so that my app can use them?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Either set them in the startup script (`/etc/init.d/yourdaemon`), or put a line in that file that looks like:

```
. /etc/yourdaemon.env
```

and put the environment variables in that file, using the syntax `export VAR=value`. On Red Hat-like systems, I believe the correct place for such a file is `/etc/sysconfig`. Debian/Ubuntu seems to have `/etc/default` for this purpose.

Comment: Tried that approach. The problem am having with that is that '/etc/init.d/yourdaemon' runs as root and so they are not available to my script, which runs as asterisk.

Comment: start-stop-daemon --start --chuid=$USER --exec $DAEMON. This executes the app as $USER

Comment: I checked the source code for the Debian version of `start-stop-daemon` and there's only one place where it touches the environment, to reset `HOME`. Can you post the `init.d` script?

Comment: It worked. I am the one that had not used `export`. Thanks. Just a small point for future users - if there's a file to be sourced when running `/etc/init.d/myscript` it's good practice to add it to `/etc/default/myscript`.

Comment: One thing I still don't understand though - how are the variables being exported to my deamons environment even though the init script is run by root?

Comment: Every process passes its environment to its child processes. The `start-stop-daemon` program gets its environment from the `init.d` script; then it switches users *internally*, running as user `asterisk` for a short while and preserving its environment; then it starts your daemon. You'd have to use the `env` command explicitly to wipe the environment clean.

Comment: @domino Your comment worked for me, not the answer. I don't know why.

Answer (score 4):

If your distro of choice is now using systemd try `systemctl edit --full asterisk.service` and consider `EnvironmentFile` and `Environment`

These files normally live here: `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service` e.g `cron.service`

Comment: Your answer helped me find this answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/455283/248589), which solved my problem.